# What template file is used for homepage pagination?

Tags: theme-development, pagination

This is most likely a duplicate and I'm just struggling for the right way to search it but what file is used to display **actual pages of posts**, not the post type of page but like /blog/page/2/ for the second page of most recent posts?

Searching reveals only how to make a template that applies to a page, but what if I just want it to apply to pagination?

The function I use to generate a link to this template is `previous_posts_link();`

Answer (score 1):

It’s the same template used for displaying the normal page (example, page.php) but you have a conditional tag `is_paged`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged
which can help you to achieve whatever you want for the other pages /2/, /3/, etc.